# SBT reports unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0 when installing Apache Spark

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to install Apache Spark. After executing the `./sbt/sbt assembly` command

These are the errors that followed :

```
Resolving org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused                                                                              
url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt- client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[error] Server access Error: Connection refused             
url=https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom

[warn]  module not found: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/raghuveer/.ivy2/local/org.eclipse.paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repo: tried
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10;0.9.0-incubating ...

UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES
org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not found
```

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not     found

**build.properties**
sbt.version=0.12.4

**sparkBuild.scala**
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

Comment: What Spark version do you compile? Could you also make the sentence *"After executing the ./sbt/sbt assembly command by changing the SBT and Scala versions does not solve the problem."* a bit clearer? I did the other changes to make the reading (and perhaps understanding) easier. Did you change anything after you had downloaded Spark source package? Do you have SBT and/or Scala installed? Have you ever used SBT on the machine? Could you show the first 20 lines of the output of `./sbt/sbt assembly`? I've just assembled Spark and had no issues with deps.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the reply,I made the error more clear, I didn't use sbt before .. the compiling stops finally and says external:mqtt/*update not found .. I checked the urls from where the mqtt is being downloaded and they doesn't exit ..so the folder in spark/external/mqtt is unchanged and not found ..can i get the files of folder spark/external/mqtt anywhere

Comment: Can you check whether you've got access to https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases? That's where the library sits in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** It's not a complete answer yet...more updates expected until it hits a final version stage when OP sorts out the issue.

There might be many factors that prevent the dependencies of the project being resolved and the project eventually assembled. Here is a recipe for nailing down the root cause of the *unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not found* issue.

Go to the project's main directory, say `~/apps/spark` and execute `./sbt/sbt`.

```
jacek:~/apps/spark
$ ./sbt/sbt
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.12.4.jar
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/)
>
```

Type `projects` in the shell to list all the projects defined under Spark.

```
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/
[info]     assembly
[info]     bagel
[info]     core
[info]     examples
[info]     external-flume
[info]     external-kafka
[info]     external-mqtt
[info]     external-twitter
[info]     external-zeromq
[info]     graphx
[info]     mllib
[info]     repl
[info]   * root
[info]     streaming
[info]     tools
[info]     yarn
[info]     yarn-alpha
```

Change the current project (marked with the star `*`) to the module that depends on `org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0` which is `external-mqtt`.

```
> project external-mqtt
[info] Set current project to spark-streaming-mqtt (in build file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/)
```

`show` the dependencies of the project.

```
> show library-dependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, io.netty:netty-all:4.0.13.Final, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:7.6.8.v20121106, org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:2.5.0.v201103041518, org.scalatest:scalatest:1.9.1:test, org.scalacheck:scalacheck:1.10.0:test, com.novocode:junit-interface:0.9:test, org.easymock:easymock:3.1:test, org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.5:test, commons-io:commons-io:2.4:test, commons-io:commons-io:2.4, org.eclipse.paho:mqtt-client:0.4.0)
```

Note the last dependency in the list which is `org.eclipse.paho:mqtt-client:0.4.0`.

Execute `update` to resolve the dependencies (that's where I expect dependency resolution errors that I'm going to ask you to add to your question).

```
> update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/}external-mqtt...
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-all;1.8.5 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 24 s, completed Feb 15, 2014 3:02:27 PM
```

As you've noticed, it worked fine for me. `update` writes a couple of resolution reports for every config in the project in the `external/mqtt/target/resolution-cache/reports` directory. Note that since resolution fails for you there might be few or no reports.

Since `org.eclipse.paho:mqtt-client:0.4.0` dependency is in `compile` scope, open `org.apache.spark-spark-streaming-mqtt_2.10-compile.xml` report in your browser (on MacOS I had to use Safari since Chrome doesn't work - dunno about other OSes).

In the report there should be the section for the `mqtt-client by org.eclipse.paho` dependency.

[image]

I however doubt you find any report in the directory since `update` keeps failing in your case.

To find ways to nail down the root cause, I made a typo in `project/SparkBuild.scala` build configuration of Spark for the URL of the `Eclipse Repo` repository where the dependency lives and removed the dependency from my local Ivy repo (it's at the very end of the file - in `mqttSettings` def - why this is a `def` not `lazy val` is another question, but I digress)

```
jacek:~/apps/spark
$ rm -rf .ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.paho/mqtt-client
```

I rerun `./sbt/sbt`.

```
jacek:~/apps/spark
$ ./sbt/sbt
Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.12.4.jar
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project/project
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/project/target/scala-2.9.2/sbt-0.12/classes...
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/)
```

And once in SBT shell, executed `external-mqtt/update` to kick off the `update` task in the `external-mqtt` project.

```
> external-mqtt/update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/apps/spark-0.9.0-incubating/}external-mqtt...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving oro#oro;2.0.8 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving commons-el#commons-el;1.0 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving hsqldb#hsqldb;1.8.0.10 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0 ...
[warn] Host repoo.eclipse.org not found. url=https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[info] You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
[warn]  module not found: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/jacek/.ivy2/local/org.eclipse.paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Local Maven Repo: tried
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-staging: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[warn] ==== Eclipse Repo: tried
[warn]   https://repoo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/paho/mqtt-client/0.4.0/mqtt-client-0.4.0.pom
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-all;1.8.5 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last external-mqtt/*:update for the full output.
[error] (external-mqtt/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.eclipse.paho#mqtt-client;0.4.0: not found
[error] Total time: 21 s, completed Feb 15, 2014 3:16:48 PM
```

It obviously failed (since there's the typo in `https://repoo.eclipse.org` - note the double `o`'s.

That's **the** output I'm asking you to add to your question so it becomes far easier to help you.

If you want to see under the covers of how SBT resolves dependencies use `last update` - there's **a whole lot of** information on the process and it *is* not for the fainthearted.

Comment: Yea I'm able to access the link repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases? and the problem is solved now.I ran sbt assembly twice and its fine now.Except that few tests failed in ./sbt/test which i need to check later.Thank you. The output for the above commands.                                                    > external-mqtt/update
[info] Updating {file:/home/raghuveer/Downloads/spark-0.9.0-incubating/}external-mqtt...
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-all;1.8.5 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Feb 19, 2014 11:30:54 PM